Laravel 11 - Disable CSRF for a route
I have a route that serves as a webhook endpoint that gets called by a remote service, but the calls that the service makes to the webhook always fail.
After some inspection of the service logs, I learned that the service is getting an HTTP error code 419.
I used to add exceptions inside the $except property of the App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken middleware, However, I'm on Laravel 11 and I can't find this middleware anymore. What is the solution to this problem?

Starting from Laravel 11, the VerifyCsrfToken middleware no longer exists within the application's skeleton.
Instead, you can specify which routes should bypass the CSRF verification process using the  validateCsrfTokens() method. You can call this method inside the withMiddleware() method callback within your bootstrap/app.php file. For example:
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Middleware;

return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting(
        web: __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php',
        commands: __DIR__.'/../routes/console.php',
        channels: __DIR__.'/../routes/channels.php',
        health: '/up',
    )
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        $middleware->validateCsrfTokens(except: [
            'you-webhook-endpoint/action-name' // <-- exclude this route
        ]);
    })->create();

More information available at the documentation at: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris
Update: You can also call the static except() method on the VerifyCsrfToken middleware class inside the boot() method of your AppServiceProvider class as following:
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot(): void
    {
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::except([
            'submit'
        ]);
    }
}


This answer has more info and seems more complete than the accepted answer, which begs the question why you didn't accept your own answer?

@DouwedeHaan You're right, I must have accepted that answer by mistake. Anyway, I didn't accept my own answer because I wanted to encourage others to come and share their answers here as well. Plus, I find it kind of strange that I accept my own answer on my own question :D

It is totally valid to accept your own answer! Go ahead and accept it :) Kudo's on the waiting so others could answer as well!

I would like to quote the answer from Laravel's documentation:

You may also exclude specific routes by providing their URIs to the
validateCsrfTokens method in your application's bootstrap/app.php file:

->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
    $middleware->validateCsrfTokens(except: [
        'stripe/*',
        'http://example.com/foo/bar',
        'http://example.com/foo/*',
    ]);
});

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/csrf#preventing-csrf-requests

Could you explain how your answer is better than the one Eyad Bereh provided?

Add your URL route in bootstrap/app.php
   ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
    $middleware->validateCsrfTokens(except: [
        'your-except-url/*',
    ]);
})

Reference : https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris

Even if the VerifyCsrfToken is not in the default app anymore, you can still use it in L11 as it is still in the framework :
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/11.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php
So you can use it as in previous version of Laravel :
create a VerifyCsrfToken custom Middleware :
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
       'your-endpoint'
    ];
}

and just add it inside your middlewareGroups inside Kernel.php :
 protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            [...]
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,


Yes, it can be done this way as well, but you will need to register the middleware inside the bootstrap/app.php file because the app/Http/Kernel.php file no longer exists in Laravel 11.
